# Non-negativity of a definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Let $\hat{x}\in(0,1)$ and $(x_{\varepsilon},y_{\varepsilon})\in(0,\hat{x})^{2}$ be a sequence such that $x_{\varepsilon},y_{\varepsilon}\to\hat{x}$ as $\varepsilon\to0$.
Assume that $f,g:[0,\hat{x}]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous functions such that $(f-g)(x)<(f-g)(\hat{x})$ for all $y\in[0,\hat{x})$

> I want to show that the integral
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{x_{\varepsilon}-\delta}\frac{f(x_{\varepsilon}-\delta)-f(z)}{\sqrt{x_{\varepsilon}-z}}dy-\int_{0}^{y_{\varepsilon}-\gamma}\frac{g(y_{\varepsilon}-\gamma)-g(z)}{\sqrt{y_{\varepsilon}-z}}dz
> $$
>   is non-negative for sufficiently small $\delta>0$ and $\gamma>0$ such that $\varepsilon<\delta<\gamma$.

It is obvious formally from sending $\delta,\gamma\to0$ and the assumption: $(f-g)(x)<(f-g)(\hat{x})$.
However, this convergece is not justified by the dominated convergence theorem since integrands in the limited integral may diverge.
I have tried giving examples of $f,g$ but I can't prove the general case.

I' glad if you give some advices or solution.